# Use C const variable in Swift as UnsafePointer

Tags: ios, c, swift, opengl-es

I have a simple C const variable in a .h/c file that looks like this:

#### data.h

```c
const float positions[9];
```

#### data.c

```c
#include "data.h"
const float positions[9] = {
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
};
```

#### Swift

How can I use this variable's data in Swift? More specifically I need to pass the data to `glVertexAttribPointer(,,,,, <#ptr: UnsafePointer<Void>#>)`.

For example, I have the following code in Swift: (I added **data.h** to the bridging header):

```swift
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), 0, positions)
// Error: '(Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float)' is not convertible to 'UnsafePointer<Void>'
glDrawArrays(GLenum(GL_TRIANGLES), 0, 3)
```

The error that I get is **'(Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float)' is not convertible to 'UnsafePointer<Void>'**.

I should point out that this is just a test app so I am not using VBOs ([Listing 8-2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH107-SW6)).

Comment: i can not understand what you want exactly

Comment: I updated the question to include the actual use case and error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the statically allocated C array goes into Swift as a tuple. Using a pointer variable instead fixes the issue.

1. In C: `const float positions[9];` translates to
   `let positions: (Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float)` in Swift
2. In C: `const float *positions;` translates to
   `var positions: UnsafePointer<Float>` in Swift **(which is what we need)**

So modifying the C files as following does the trick:

#### data.h

```c
const float *positions;
```

#### data.c

```c
#include "data.h"
const float _positions[9] = {
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
};
const float *positions = _positions;
```

#### Swift

```swift
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), 0, positions)
```

Having the array as a tuple in Swift seems very strange though, if anyone has any thoughts on this I would appreciate some feedback.